# Listener return false will only stop the propagation of an event to other listeners? or else stop related event as well? (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

For event listener thing, I created a observer `(TeamObserver)` for a model and in the observer i have deleting event and there i call `(event(new TeamDeletingEvent($team)))`. I have created a deleting event `(TeamDeletingEvent)` and related with two listeners.
When i try to delete particular model `(Team)` data then related observer deleting method fire deleting event `(event(new TeamDeletingEvent($team)))` and it call related listeners. Here my question is there are two listeners so first listener will return false then second listener didn't call but what about deleting particular data?

Anyone have any idea? Actually i am new to laravel and i am currently working in laravel 7.

Comment: please post the code that you are working and having the issue.

Comment: My question is `TeamDeletingEvent` related listener return false. Then deleting `Team` model will stop or not? I think code is not needed. Thanks